# I want to know what does np.float32 means

Tags: python, numpy

The code I'm using is to change the perspective of a given image. Can anyone please explain what `np.float32([[320,15], [700,215], [85,610], [530,780]])` does, and what `np.float32` is used for?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('images/scan.jpg')

cv2.imshow('Original', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Coordinates of the 4 points of the original image
points_A = np.float32([[320,15], [700,215], [85,610], [530,780]])

# Coordinates of the 4 points of the desired output
# We use a ratio of an A4 Paper 1 : 1.41
points_B = np.float32([[0,0], [420,0], [0,594], [420,594]])
 
# Use the two sets of four points to compute 
# the Perspective Transformation matrix, M    
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(points_A, points_B)
 
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (420,594))
 
cv2.imshow('warpPerspective', warped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's generating a 2D list of `float32` (a **float** type with **32** bits).

---

The formatting is a bit hard to understand at first but, basically, it's creating one list with `[]`, and inside that list it's creating new lists (`[], []`) with two variables. So, each item in the first list is a second list, with two items in the second list:

```
points_B = [  [item1, item2], [item3, item4]  ]
```

To access the second item, we could write:

```
x = points_B[0][1]
```

---

The `float32` datatypes in the list are referring to points which are then being passed into `getPerspectiveTransform` which is being used to compute the transformation matrix, which, to my understanding, just defines the area of the image that you want to warp.

Answer (score 0):

np.float32(a) is equivalent to np.array(a, dtype=np.float32). it's a data type of some size.

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]                      # a(list,len=3): [1, 2, 3]
b = np.float32(a)                  # b(numpy.ndarray,s=(3,),dtype=float32): [1.00, 2.00, 3.00]
c = np.array(a, dtype=np.float32)  # c(numpy.ndarray,s=(3,),dtype=float32): [1.00, 2.00, 3.00]

a = [100, 200, 300]             # a = [100, 200, 300]
b = np.uint8(a)                 # b(numpy.ndarray,s=(3,),dtype=uint8): [100, 200, 44]
c = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8) # c = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8)
d = np.int32(a)                 # d(numpy.ndarray,s=(3,),dtype=int32): [100, 200, 300]
```

Notice on the second example that an unsigned int8 is not big enough for the number 300 - hence overflow (max val for uint8 is 255).